# Convert string using Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I convert the string `russ(ai)(edocn)cup` to `russiancodecup` using Ruby?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about (maybe because you don't say what your problem is)

Comment: Looks like the OP is trying to take any substring that is in parentheses, invert the substring and then remove the parenthesis.  Can you confirm/deny user1506690?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `gsub` with a block, you can replace any match of a regular expression by the result of this block.

```
s = "russ(ai)(edocn)cup"
s.gsub(/\(([^)]*)\)/) {$1.reverse}  # => "russiancodecup"
```

Here the regular expression will match any non-`)` character between brackets. Then it will send `reverse` to `$1` which is gonna be the content between brackets.

`$0` will be the complete match and `$n`, the nth "submatch". (anybody for the correct word ?)

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is 'capturing group'

Comment: Shouldn't it be `s = 'russ(ai)(edocn)cup'`?

Comment: You probably want `*?` rather than `*`.

Comment: Still not work for me :(
s = "russ(ai)(edocn)cup"
s.gsub(/\(([^)]*)\)/) {$1.reverse}
puts s #=> russ(ai)(edocn)cup

Comment: You forgot to escape the `/`. The correct regular expression is `/\(([^)]*)\)/`.

Comment: <code>
s = "russ(ai)(edocn)cup"
s.gsub(/\(([^)]*)\)/) {$1.reverse}

puts s

#=> russ(ai)(edocn)cup
</code>

Comment: I meant you forgot to escape the brackets.